# How to transfer serial data or plot wirelessly on an arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, wireless, data

I have an arduino uno and an accelerometer connected reading vibrations. I want to be able to send the serial data or serial plot wirelessly from the arduino to any program(recommendations will be considered) on the pc without using the USB port on the pc. Is it possible?

I have an arduino ethernet shield, bluetooth modules HC-05 and HC-10 all at hand if they will be helpful. 
please help, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `serial plot` is just serial data .... google is your friend ... find a tutorial about the Arduino and HC-05

Comment: so i gave the arduino an ip address through the ethernet shield and it is reading the data when i type in the ip address in my computer, now I just need a way how to plot this data and I think I need a database for that kind of work. Any suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: you want to collect data and then draw a chart it in a spreadsheet offline? with HC-05 you could draw realtime in the IDE Serial Plotter

Comment: yes i want to collect data and then draw it in a spreadsheet offline, realtime plotting would also be a great add on.

Comment: paired HC-05 creates a COM port which you can select in Arduino IDE and use it with Serial Monittor/Plotter

Comment: actually i cant use the bluetooth modules anymore, do you know anything about wonderware?

Comment: so which part should be wireless? the communication with the sensor or the communication with PC or both?